# How can I write the results of this loop to a text file?

Tags: python

I have a loop and I am trying to write the printed output of the loop to a file. The loop does in fact print the desired results to the screen but when I view the file I end up with a row of integers.

I'm using Google Colaboratory - hence the "!" in front of any shell commands

I have tried opening files outside the loop but it still does not seem to work.

This is my original code which is causing me the problems:

```
string = 'MAJSHDDJDU'
z_list = 'AVILMFYWSTNQCGPRHKDE~*'

with open("file.txt", "a") as file_txt:
  for i in range(len(string)):
      for j in range(len(z_list)):
          print(string[:i] + z_list[j] + string[i + 1:])
          file_txt.write(str(i))
```

Actual result: The loop prints the desired result - but does not write the desired result to the file.

```
AAJSHDDJDU
VAJSHDDJDU
IAJSHDDJDU
LAJSHDDJDU
MAJSHDDJDU
FAJSHDDJDU
YAJSHDDJDU
WAJSHDDJDU
....
```

Instead viewing the file returns:

```
!cat file.txt
000000000000000000000011111111111111111111112222...
```

Desired result: I'm viewing the file on google colaboratory

```
!cat file.txt 
AAJSHDDJDU
VAJSHDDJDU
IAJSHDDJDU
LAJSHDDJDU
MAJSHDDJDU
FAJSHDDJDU
YAJSHDDJDU
WAJSHDDJDU
.....
```

Comment: you are just writing `str(i)` Also don't write to the file at every iteration. Better accumulate your output in a variable and write at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop returns the desired result in output because you are printing the manipulated string , while writing into file you are just writing your iterator vale as `str(i)`

Below code will give you the intended results:

```
string = 'MAJSHDDJDU'
z_list = 'AVILMFYWSTNQCGPRHKDE~*'
l=[] #list to store all your combinations of string
for i in range(len(string)):
    for j in range(len(z_list)):
        l.append(string[:i] + z_list[j] + string[i + 1:])

with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    for i in l:
        f.write(i+"\n")
```

please let me know if this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

First,  you are not writing the same thing to console as you are to file.  If you use an intermediate variable `tempstring` to build the string you want to output, you can easily see that the same argument is being passed to `print()` and `f.write()`.

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    for j in range(len(z_list)):
        tempstring = string[:i] + z_list[j] + string[i + 1:]
        print(tempstring)
        file_txt.write(tempstring)
```

Second, you do not write new lines.  To write new lines to file you need to do so explicitly, `print()` automatically adds a new line each time it is called, `write()` does not so you need to add a `"\n"` in there:

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    for j in range(len(z_list)):
        tempstring = string[:i] + z_list[j] + string[i + 1:]
        print(tempstring)
        file_txt.write(tempstring + "\n")
```

Now this should be working the way you want, but it is rather inefficient for large strings and lists.  Step 3 would be to save your `tempstring`s as you go and write to file all at once after your initial loops.  I'll leave this part to you.